# how to post a link in comments with a specific name?

Tags: html

Why doesn't hyperlink work under youtube comments?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can only post links with custom names in a format which the platform supports. You cannot simply write html on a website and expect for it to come out correctly.

You need to check with what the site supports, for example typing html code *is supported* on stack overflow, but evidently it is not on YouTube.

Comment: Do you know how to post links with custom names on youtube？